# setState in Reactjs is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, setstate

I'm new to react and I am trying to hit an API using `fetch` and then `setState` to a state variable but it is throwing the error as

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function
```

[Here is the code -> CodeSandboxLink](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-breeze-ori5f?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, setState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      setState(data);
    });
  console.log("dasdasd", person);
  return <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(person)}</div>;
}
```

Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: you named the variable `setPerson`, not `setState`. call `setPerson(data)`

Comment: You should post code in the question...... not a link

Comment: @NicholasTower, can you please refresh the link again?

Answer (score 5):

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setPerson(data); // You Need this For set Person to `state person`
      });
  }, []);
  console.log("dasdasd", person);
  return <div className="App">{JSON.stringify(person)}</div>;
}
```

API useState:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

API useEffect:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: When I used `setPerson`, it is repeatedly hitting the API and never stopping. here is working demo link https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-ramanujan-1ltcw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Mahesh Wrap your api call in https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: You've put the fetch code in the body of your component, so it's happening on every render. When do you want to fetch? If it's when the component mounts, put it in a useEffect

Comment: You should use `fetch` inside `useEffect` (Similar to `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`)

Comment: @Ergis I wanted to fetch in the initial load of page. I am not using useEffect because it would result data after the page is rendered. In simple terms, I want to fetch the data and do something with the data

Comment: good question my Friend. I changed my answer. try this

Comment: What's the difference? You would still need to wait for the response (display a loading indicator or something).

Comment: @Ergis, I want to pass this `person` data to `useState` Variables. Since useState happens in initial load, if we use useEffect I wont be able to pass data to useState variables

Comment: @Mahdizoraghi so there is no way to use `setState` and make the code work?